# Android navigation drawer onDrawerSlide is not called

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I've put following code into **onDrawerSlide** method of **navigation drawer** in order to move content when drawer is opening.

```
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            container.setTranslationX(slideOffset * drawerView.getWidth());
            mDrawerLayout.bringChildToFront(drawerView);
            mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
        }
```

It works perfectly almost always, except of first app run - I open drawer programmatically to teach user using it.
So, when I'm calling

```
if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
   }
```

drawer is opening, but **onDrawerSlide** is not called.
I suppose, reason is that something does not have enough time to load, but I don't know what exactly and how escape this.
It works when I'm calling **openDrawer** in a few seconds after run (via **Handler**), but it looks terrible on UI.

PS. Tried to call **openDrawer** in **onCreate**, **onResume**, in calling **Activity** - still no result.

PPS. Also I'm unable to call **onDrawerSlide** directly - because I don't know **slideOffset** value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you open drawer programmatically to teach user using it, you need to call `DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)` with a `Handler` or an `AsyncTask` which will change in time the value of `slideOffset` which is in `[0, 1]`. 

Just like:

```
    private Handler mUIHandler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case UPDATE_SLIDING_INDEX:
            double slideOffSet= (double)msg.obj;
            if (slideOffSet> 0.0 && slideOffSet<= 1.0) {
                drawerListener.onDrawerSlide(drawer, slideOffSet);
                Message message = mUIHandler.obtainMessage();
                message.what = UPDATE_SLIDING_INDEX;
                message.obj = slideOffSet- 0.1;
                mUIHandler.sendMessageDelayed(message, 100);
            } else {
                //To do something here.
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Then you call like this:

```
Message message = mUIHandler.obtainMessage();
message.what = UPDATE_SLIDING_INDEX;
message.obj = 0.8;
mUIHandler.sendMessage(message);
```

Comment: Its not bad, actually I can call it even without Handler. But how can I know value of slideOffSet (you put it to 0.8)?

Comment: Oops, seems I was quite stupid to create this topic and ask this question :-) I just can pass 1 as slideOffSet and it automatically would move content to whole drawer width. Need to check it.

Comment: Ok, calling openDrawer in a some time did the trick. Though I used Handler.postDelayed (code is some shorter, than in answer above), idea is the same. So I'll accept this answer, thanks SilentKnight.

Answer (score 0):

when  `mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(....);` is called before or after of the below if condition.

```
if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
}
```

If it is after, obviously the onDrawerSlide won't be called.

If it is before then you should debug.

Comment: For sure, I set listener before this check.